# Set margins in RecyclerView adapter without xml

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to set the margins of my RecyclerView row without using xml because sometimes I have two lines and I need to change margins dynamicly. But when I launch the program no margin is set. Is there someone who has an answer what I did wrong?

My xml file for understanding:

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settingTitle"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settingSubtitle"
        android:layout_below="@id/settingTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my onBind from my adapter:

```js
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MySettingHolder holder, int position) {
        // Setting for one entry
        Settings setting = settingList.get(position);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


        // If the settingSubtitle is empty it should be not visible and just the settingTitle
        if (setting.getSettingSubtitle().equals("")) {
            params.setMargins(0, 18, 0, 18);
            holder.settingTitle.setLayoutParams(params);
            holder.settingTitle.setText(setting.getSettingTitle());
            holder.settingSubtitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            // Set Margins for settingTitle
            params.setMargins(0, 18, 0, 18);
            holder.settingTitle.setLayoutParams(params);
            // Set Margins for settingSubtitle
            params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 18);
            holder.settingSubtitle.setLayoutParams(params);
            holder.settingTitle.setText(setting.getSettingTitle());
            holder.settingSubtitle.setText(setting.getSettingSubtitle());
        }
    }
```

Comment: you should set params to your recyclerview

Comment: @santoshkumar And what do you think I'm doing here?

Comment: recyclerview.setParams(params);

Comment: @santoshkumar I don't know what you mean what I should do with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I've tried a lot of days getting my problem fixed. The other answers wasn't very helpfully. My question was how I can set the margin without `XML` to my TextView in a RecyclerView row (Because sometimes I have just one TextView instead of two):

[image]

This is how to define the margin new in an adapter in Android in my situation:

```js
// Create new LayoutParams object
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

// Define values in dp and calculate pixels from it because margins are with pixels
int dpValueBottom = 14;
int dpValueLeft = 40;
float d = customContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int marginStandard = (int)(dpValueBottom * d);
int marginLeft = (int)(dpValueLeft * d);

holder.settingImage.setImageResource(setting.getSettingImageUrl());
// If the settingSubtitle is empty it should be not visible and just the settingTitle
if (setting.getSettingSubtitle().equals("")) {
    holder.settingTitle.setText(setting.getSettingTitle());
    holder.settingSubtitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    // Get settingTitle TextView
    TextView settingTitle = holder.settingTitle;

    // Set margin to params
    params.setMargins(marginLeft, marginStandard, 0, marginStandard);

    // Set params to settingTitle
    settingTitle.setLayoutParams(params);

} else {
    holder.settingTitle.setText(setting.getSettingTitle());
    holder.settingSubtitle.setText(setting.getSettingSubtitle());
}
```

I hope I can help someone with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, You want it to affect the whole `RecyclerView` and not each row? Below is a solution for that.

When you initialize your `RecyclerView` in your `Activity/Fragment` before you go into your adapter you should set the margins there if you want to affect the whole of your `RecyclerView`, `onBindViewHolder` binds the layout you've provided for each row and manipulates those widgets there, row by row so the margins will affect each row rather than your `RecyclerView`.

An example of the code inside your Activity/Fragment would be:

```
 recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
 recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
 RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 params.setMargins(0, 18, 0, 18);
 recyclerView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: No I want to effect each row. Sometimes I have a row with two titles and sometimes with just one. So each row need his own margin depending on the textviews who are in the row. Look at my if statement. There you can see what I mean.

Comment: No problem buddy. I'll edit my answer when I'm back on a laptop.

Comment: Hey mate what is with your answer? :) I'm still waiting

Comment: My apologies buddy. I'll sort it tomorrow, it was a busy day at work today.

Comment: can you post your full adapter code, and where you get the data for the Settings in your activity please buddy.

Comment: I'm on a desktop now so i can help out.