# Change XML Color to Drawable

Tags: android, xml, colors, drawable

I want to change the color of the following XML into images. so the point I want mebubah color to the picture. how do I do?

**XML:**

```xml
<color name="spring_loaded_panel_color">#50e602ee</color>
```

Comment: Put your code, please. Do you mean `ImageView`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Welcome @Chocolate, Please provide proper information.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot change xml color at runtime. but you can create Drawable at runtime and you can change the color.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a ColorDrawable.

```
ColorDrawable cd = new ColorDrawable(YOUR_COLOR_HERE);
```

Here you can get the color from resources using:

```
ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.yourColor)
```

Your final code might look like:

```
ColorDrawable cd = new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color. spring_loaded_panel_color));
```

Comment: Can you take a look at my question? If you can help me I'll give you my vote :) http://stackoverflow.com/q/41745279/7267238